# what are the steps need to consider to migrate Windows based applicaotin from 1.1 to .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me main steps to consider while migrating 1.1 to 3.5 windows based application?

What are the steps need to consider at initially while planing for migration?
as per i know this applicatin i need to migrate like wsf and wpf and soo on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade the projects to .NET 3.5 Framework and then build the solution. Fix any compilation errors (there will likely be a few), and then you will need a large QA effort to make sure you didn't break anything. It's really more of just a time sink than anything you need a specific plan for.

If you can manage it, see if you can write unit tests for your app, and then after the upgrade, make sure all those unit tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/net2_cs2_newfeatures.aspx

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/.net-3.5-language-enhancements/

I guess you should look through new features and check whether a change in code is necessary for that new feature.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of effort involved and the changing to newer technologies like WPF, I think you are better off doing a re-write of the application in 3.5.  We have had some ugly upgrades done at my place of work that may compile and run as 3.5 but are really just hacked 1.1 applications.